# What's the proper way to create a static sentinel node

Tags: c++, tree

I want to have a single instance of a sentinel node that other nodes can use as part of their constructor.  I tried

```
struct Node;
static Node sentinel(0);
struct Node{
    Node(int val): next(&sentinal), val(val) {}
    Node *next;
    int val;
};

int main() {
    Node *node = new Node(42);
}
```

This doesn't work because the

```
'Node sentinel' has initializer but incomplete type
```

What is the proper way to create a single sentinel node for multiple value nodes?

Comment: Maybe make the sentinel a pointer that is initialized when the full definition of the class is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your sentinel a static member of `Node`.

```
struct Node{
    Node(int val): next(&sentinel), val(val) {}
    Node *next;
    int val;
    static Node sentinel;
};

Node Node::sentinel(0);

int main() {
    Node *node = new Node(42);
}
```